# Understanding the type of "failwith" in F#?

Tags: exception, types, f#

How to make sense of the type of failwith in F#?

```
> failwith;;
val it : (string -> 'a)
```

Why is it associated with a generic type 'a instead of an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `'a` is the type of the return value, and a function cannot return values of multiple different types. If `failwith` returned an `Exception`, any other path in the function calling `failwith` would need to return an `Exception` as well. Keep in mind that, when a function calls `failwith` (which throws an exception) on a certain path, that path actually doesn't return a value, but rather interrupts the execution flow.

In the case below, the generic return type of `failwith` is forced to be an `int`, because a different path in the code returns an `int`.

[image]

Consider then this case instead, where we actually return an `Exception`. Notice that it generates a compilation error.

[image]